# How to store line number in node using JJTree JavaCC

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc, interpretation

I try to create a compiler of a simplified language and I want to know how to store meta information like line number in my node. This will permit me to make a step-by-step interpretation. So I need to find the line of the current instruction in the concrete source text from the instruction node.

Can someone help me with this problem ?

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class `SourceCoords` to hold the information you want.

Add field to the SimpleNode class

```
  private SourceCoords myCoords ;
  public void setCoords( SourceCoords toSet ) { myCoords = toSet ; }
  public SourceCoords getCoords() { return myCoords ; }
```

In the options add

```
NODE_SCOPE_HOOK=true;
```

In your parser class add the following declarations

```
void jjtreeOpenNodeScope(Node n) {
    ((SimpleNode)n).setCoords( new SourceCoords( file, getToken(1).beginLine ) ) ;
}
void jjtreeCloseNodeScope(Node n) {
}
```